# AWS Athena case sensitive orc.column.index.access=false?

Tags: amazon-web-services, hive, presto, amazon-athena

I've created a table in Athena with below config

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE `extern` (`FirstName` STRING, `LastName` STRING, `Email` STRING, `Phone` STRING, `AddressLine1` STRING, `City` STRING, `State` STRING, `PostalCode` STRING,  
`time_on_page` DECIMAL(10,3), `page` STRING, `login_time` TIMESTAMP) ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcSerde' 
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ('orc.column.index.access'='false') 
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcInputFormat' 
OUTPUTFORMAT 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcOutputFormat'
LOCATION 's3://location/' tblproperties ("orc.compress"="ZLIB")
```

and when I query it with `select * from extern` I get empty values for all columns except for `time_on_page`, `page` and `login_time`. However, this returns data in all columns if I use `('orc.column.index.access'='true')`. 
The schema of the column names in the ORC file are exact with what's defined in the create statement.

```
File Version: 0.12 with ORC_135
Rows: 13559
Compression: ZLIB
Compression size: 131072
Type: struct<FirstName:string,LastName:string,Email:string,Phone:string,AddressLine1:string,City:string,State:string,PostalCode:string,time_on_page:decimal(10,3),page:string,login_time:timestamp>
```

The question is, could it be possible that when `orc.column.index.access=false` the engine tries to read column names with case sensitive constraints?

Comment: Can you set `orc.schema.evolution.case.sensitive=false` and try?

Comment: @mazaneicha still no luck!

Answer (score 0):

Apparently Presto version of Amazon is based on PrestoDB and this feature doesn't seem to be available on Prestodb as of this writing; Prestosql, however, seem to have had this support from Release 312 and onwards (ref: https://github.com/prestosql/presto/issues/802).
The solution is to make sure the schema in the ORC file uses lowercase column name for it to be matched with names from hive metastore (which are always lowercased).

Debug code for presto db: https://github.com/prestodb/presto/blob/6647e13f64883f7cfa89221d91b981bcc3a57618/presto-hive/src/main/java/com/facebook/presto/hive/HiveUtil.java#L984
https://github.com/prestodb/presto/blob/95bcb3947cad1570e19a0adaebc58009aa362ada/presto-orc/src/main/java/com/facebook/presto/orc/OrcReader.java#L130